# Define a $T$ on $ A \times B$ by $((a_1,b_1),(a_2,b_2)) \in T \leftrightarrow (a_1,a_2) \in R$. Prove that $T$ is an equivalence relation.

Tags: equivalence-relations

> Let $R$ be an equivalence relation on $A$ and let $S$ be an equivalence relation on $B$. Define a $T$ on $ A \times B$ by $((a_1,b_1),(a_2,b_2)) \in T \leftrightarrow (a_1,a_2) \in R$ and $(b_1,b_2) \in S$. Prove that $T$ is an equivalence relation.

My attempt:

We need to prove that $T$ is an equivalence relation.

Definition 6.2.3 states that $R$ is an equivalence relation if $R$ is reflexive, symmetric, and transitive.

R is reflexive if $(\forall x \in S)(x,x) \in R]$

R is symmetric if $(\forall x,y \in S)[(x,y) \in R \rightarrow (y,x) \in R]$

R is transitive if $(\forall x, y, z \in S)[((x,y) \in R \land (y,z) \in R) \rightarrow (x,z) \in R]$

---

What if we let $x = (a_1,b_1), y = (a_2,b_2),$ and $z=(a_3,b_3)$?

For $T$ to be reflexive, we need $(\forall (a_1),(b_1) \in S)[((a_1,b_1),(a_1,b_1)) \in T $

For all $T$ to be symmetric, we need $(\forall (a_1,b_1),(a_2,b_2) \in S)[(a_1,b_1),(a_2,b_2) \in T \rightarrow (a_2,b_2),(a_1,b_1) \in T$

For all $T$ to be transitive, we need $(\forall (a_1,b_1),(a_2,b_2),(a_3,b_3) \in S]((a_1,b_1),(a_2,b_2) \in T \land ((a_2,b_2),(a_3,b_3)) \in T \rightarrow ((a_1,b_1), (a_3,b_3)) \in T$

We have proven that $T$ is an equivalence relation.

I'm not sure if I did this correctly, but the problem did ask to prove that $T$ is an equivalence relation and the definition fits perfectly. I don't know if there's some other fancy thing that I need to do or is that it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may need some further justification -- that is, it seems as though you're stating what you need to be true and not *why* it is true. (Of course, this may also be me misunderstanding your notation.)

For example:

Let $\sim_{T}, \sim_{R}, \sim_{S}$ denote relation by $T,R$ and $S$, respectively.

To show $T$ is reflexive, we must have $(a,b) \sim_{T} (a,b)$ for all $(a,b) \in A \times B$. Because $R$ and $S$ are both equivalence relations [hence reflexive], we have that $a \sim_{R} a$ for all $a \in A$ and $b \sim_{S} b$ for all $b \in B$. Then $(a,b) \sim_{T} (a,b)$ for all $(a,b) \in A \times B$.

Now, suppose that $(a_{1},b_{1}) \sim_{T} (a_{2},b_{2})$. Because $R$ is symmetric, $a_{1} \sim_{R} a_{2}$ implies $a_{2} \sim_{R} a_{1}$ for all $a_{1},a_{2} \in A$. Likewise, $b_{1} \sim_{S} b_{2}$ implies $b_{2} \sim_{S} b_{1}$ for all $b_{1},b_{2} \in B$. Hence $(a_{2},b_{2}) \sim_{T} (a_{1},b_{1})$ and $T$ is symmetric.

Finally, suppose that $(a_{1},b_{1}) \sim_{T} (a_{2},b_{2})$ and $(a_{2},b_{2}) \sim_{T} (a_{3},b_{3})$. By transitivity of $R$, $a_{1} \sim_{R} a_{2}$ and $a_{2} \sim_{R} a_{3}$ implies $a_{1} \sim_{R} a_{3}$ for all $a_{1},a_{2},a_{3} \in A$. Similarly, due to transitivity of $S$ we have that $b_{1} \sim_{S} b_{2}$ and $b_{2} \sim_{S} b_{3}$ implies $b_{1} \sim_{S} b_{3}$ for all $b_{1},b_{2},b_{3} \in B$. Thus $(a_{1},b_{1}) \sim_{T} (a_{3},b_{3})$ and $T$ is transitive, hence an equivalence relation on $A \times B$.

There isn't anything fancy, as you said, but it's a matter of unpacking definitions. I'm not sure if the above is the sort of format you're looking for, but I thought I'd write things out explicitly with words rather than symbols.

Comment: yes this helps a lot... I should've expanded on top of what I've written.